# etcd v3 API unavailable

Tags: kubernetes, etcd, coredns

I'm trying to deploy CoreDNS with etcd as the backend. I've gotten through most of the configuration of both etcd and CoreDNS, but I'm trying to document for the developers how to push records into etcd for CoreDNS.

Reading all of the etcd v3 documentation, there was a change from the v2 API in etcd v2 to v3 API in etcd v3. There are multiple pages that refer to API calls being made using URLs such as:

```
curl -L http://localhost:2379/v3beta/kv/put \
  -X POST -d '{"key": "Zm9v", "value": "YmFy"}'
```

I've tried multiple combinations of the http://IP:2379/[v3alpha | v3beta | v3]/kv/put and I always get a not found or 404 not found.

This works fine:

```
curl http://IPADDRESS:2379/v2/keys/test/local/test -XPUT -d '{"host":"IPADDRESS","ttl":60}'
```

But this doesn't:

```
curl http://IPADDRESS:2379/[v3alpha | v3beta | v3]/keys/test/local/test -XPUT -d '{"host":"IPADDRESS","ttl":60}'
```

Is there something I'm missing from the documentation?

I'm running etcd v 3.3.12.

Comment: Which specific release are you deploying?

Comment: Bigger issue: The v3 API is gRPC-based, no longer JSON/restful at all; curl is no longer the preferred way of working with it. The examples you're referring to are for using the [`grpc-gateway`](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway) proxy server, but that's not ideal (and require you to actually be running that service; it would do some good to show details of how you did your installation so we can be sure that software is actually running).

Comment: Meant to include this in my post. The version of etcd is 3.3.12.

I'm running etcd from the latest Linux binary provided. Did not build it myself. @CharlesDuffy, which details do you need specifically? It is deployed and I've been able to successfully test using the v2 URLs. The v3 URL does not work as documented.

Comment: I faced this issue too, after many many times of changing of etcd.conf, I found that if the etcd is started without --config-file, the v3 rest api works fine. but if it's started with --config-file, even specifies an empty file, the v3 rest api will not works. very strange.

Answer (score 4):

After checked the etcd source codes, I finally have found the RC of this issue. In etcd 3.3.0, the default value of the config flag "enable-grpc-gateway" is false if the etcd loads config from the yaml config file, but the default value is true if etcd loads config flag from commandline. so add below lines to your etcd config file can solve the issue.

```
enable-grpc-gateway: true
```

I tried the etcd 3.3.13, it's fixed in this version.